# Disallow calls to certain classes in java extensions

Tags: java, jar, extensibility

We are building an engine that will allow us to add new jar files whenever, load those jar files and look for some specific functionality, and run the code that exposes that functionality. Current plan is to use the ServiceLoader to do so (just an extra detail; I'm not married to that idea). For the moment let's assume that we completely control which jar files are going to be loaded (big assumption--I'd guess I'm going to eventually post something about that too).

Given all that, I would like to restrict access in those extensions to certain classes. For a fake example, we want to ensure that instead of using `java.io.PrintStream`, they use `our.better.PrintStreamSolution`.

I really don't have a good idea of what I could do here. Since for the time being, we own the code that will go out as extensions, we could just do very thorough code reviews but I'd rather do either a static analysis at install time or actually throw errors at runtime. Any idea how one would would accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to whitelist the APIs. Reflective APIs appear all over the place, so you can't realistically blacklist. To do this, you'd need to go through the jars using a library such as ASM. Whilst you could use `URLClassLoader` with a custom URL connection handler, I would suggest a custom class loader. I strongly suggest avoiding anything to do with global state, such as `ServiceLoader`.

Comment: What is wrong with ServiceLoader and what is a better/different way to get a class that implements a specific interface (or has a well-known name, I guess) from a jar?

Comment: @SirPentor It uses ambient [global] state. / Take the name of your class; look it up in your class loader (be specific about which one); use `asSubclass`; find the `Constructor` (don't miss this step); call `newInstance`. (There are possible variations, such as using a constant field instead of a constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a special ClassLoader to read the JAR, and override the method "loadClass" so that if the classloader tries to load a class from the "java.io" package, it throws  SecurityException. Something like this:

```
protected Class loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
                                            throws ClassNotFoundException { 
       if (name.startsWith("java.io")) 
             throw new SecurityException("java.io access not allowed on extensions");

        return super.loadClass(name,resolve); 
}
```

Remember to implement your classloading logic in the overriden findClass method of your ClassLoader.

This check can be defeated if the extension can get hold of another classloader (like the system classloader) to load the 'forbidden' classes.

As shown in the comments, the alternative to use SecurityManager is possible only if the security manager can identify that a package is being accesed from within an extension.

Comment: Please correct me if I am mistaken, but couldn't the extension just call `Object.class.getClassLoader().loadClass()` to bypass your suggestion? I am reasonably sure the only solution is to mess with SecurityManagers, but I don't have the experience there either, and I don't think I know anyone who does.

Comment: Object.class.getClassLoader() should return null (actually, all classes in the JRE should return null, as they were loaded by the bootstrap Classloader), so you should be pretty safe. Of course, they can use the same trick using classes from your engine (that will be actually loaded by the system classloader).  
So yes, You're right, the check can be bypassed. So messing with SecurityManagers it is.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer and I assume that's because I don't know enough about the subject. Any suggestions on background reading for this?

Comment: This isn't going to work. Amongst other things, reflective APIs will get around it. You shouldn't be able to [directly] get hold of a `ClassLoader` instance through `Class.getClassLoader` unless the immediate caller (yeah, dismal API) was loaded from an ancestor class loader.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline are you saying that the ClassLoader solution won't work or that the SecurtyManager solution won't work? My understanding based on these comments and the research I've done today is that the ClassLoader solution won't work.

Comment: @SirPentor The class loader one wont be effective. For the same reason the security manager as presented wont work. You should be able to deny access to whole packages using it, but don't check the immediate caller.

Comment: "don't check the immediate caller"?

Comment: @SirPentor follow the Oracle tutorials about SecurityManagers and ClassLoaders. Google "how to create a Security manager in Java" and "how to create a custom class loader in java" (that's what I did). And finally read the Javadocs. After some time, it all makes sense.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I see what you mean, you're right. Unless you can identify in the callstack that the package is being referenced from an extension, the SecurityManager is of no use. I'll remove that code until I find a better way.

Comment: @Soronthar The immediate caller is useless, because if it comes from a reflective API that caller will not be the code that is in charge. However, you can do a package.access check which uses the current AccessControlContext.